# Отслеживание MySQL запросов в Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, логирование

Есть MAMP на маке. Нужно отслеживать в реальном времени все mysql запросы к серверу. Как это реализовать?

Comment: вести лог медленных запросов и поставить время равное нулю ))) либо через `show full processlist` мониторить

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию логгирование отключено, так как это довольно затратная операция. Однако, можно включить логгирование запросов, для этого в конфигурационном файле my.cnf, в секции [myqld] следует

```
general_log=1
general_log_file=/path/to/log
```

Вместо /path/to/log следует подставить путь к лог-файлу. Логгирование включается после перезагрузки сервера. Чтобы следить за логом в реальном времени, можно воспользоваться командой `tail`, передав ей параметр `-f` и при необходимости количество выводимых последних строк

```
tail -200f /path/to/log
```